# Validate contenteditable on enter and not on clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using contenteditable so as people can edit a text.
So when you edit the text thas has contenteditable = true, if you click somewhere else in the page, it will "validate" your text and replace the older.
That's not the comportment I'd like it to have because the user has no way to get back to the older text except by refreshing the page.

To me, it should validate the text only if you press the Enter Key and not if you click somewhere else. If you click somewhere else then it should get back to the older text.

Any idea how to make it ?
Thanks ! :)

Comment: what did you try before ?

Comment: You need to take a look to take a look on the [HelpCenter](https://stackoverflow.com/help) (section Asking). Can you add code that you try ? Something to work with ?

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the box, you can store its value into a `var`, and when they click away, reset the box to that `var`.

If the Enter key doesn't already validate, here's some pseudocode as to what you could do:

```
var oldvalue = "";
function OnClickBox() {
    oldvalue = (yourelement).value;
}

function OnClickAway() {
    (yourelement).value = oldvalue;
}

function Validate() {
    (yourelement).value = yourvalidationfunction(yourelement.value);
}

document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    key = e.which || e.KeyCode;

    if (e.keyCode === 16) { //enter key
        Validate();
    }
}
```

Then you assign the box's `onclick` to `OnClickBox()`, and unselecting the box to `OnClickAway()`.

And for future posts, please include some code as to what you have tried already, and for better context as to your question.